# How to send a normal variable's value from PHP to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, reactjs, react-native

I have the below piece of code in my `test.php` file. The code mainly has a variable defined in PHP, and I want to send it to a JavaScript function so it could POST it. Here's the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Payment Receipt</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
...
if($row) {
    $myValue = 'Hi there!'; //the PHP variable (currently has a sample value, but will be string only)

    //JS starts    

    echo <<<JS001
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var msg = {$myValue}; //trying to set it to a JS var, so I could send it to below function.
    var ThunkableWebviewerExtension = {
        postMessage: function (message) {
            if (window.ReactNativeWebView) {
                window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(message);
            } else {
                window.parent.postMessage(message, '*');
            }
        }
    };
    
    ThunkableWebviewerExtension.postMessage(msg);
    console.log(msg);
    alert('Message Sent');
    </script>
JS001;
    
} else {
    echo 'Incorrect Value';
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

But when I run this code, I get this error on console : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`. What should I do if I want to send just a simple string value to the JS code? What's wrong currently?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Payment Receipt</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
...
if($row) {
    $myValue = 'Hi there!';
?>
<script>
var msg = "<?php echo $myValue; ?>"; //trying to set it to a JS var, so I could send it to below
//Your remaining js script here ...

</script>
<?php } else { 
//your else condition
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, @mPareek! I just want to confirm two things - 1) I see you haven't put a semicolon at the end of `$myValue`. Is it on purpose? 2) Breaking the PHP code into two parts wouldn't cause any errors, right?

Comment: #1 Oh, it was a typo. I missed it. You can put it there. #2 NO it would not cause any errors.

Comment: Thanks. my JS function would also be there in the `<script>` tags, right?

Comment: Thanks, I'll check and see if this code works for me.

Comment: @BigSantuary Please note I have added `echo` before variable. You have to echo the variable to be able to use it in js.

Comment: I think $myValue should be defined with a default value before if condition to avoid unexpected error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Payment Receipt</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
...
if($row) {
    $myValue = 'Hi there!'
?>
<script>
var msg = "<?php $myValue; ?>";

</script>
<?php } else { 
  echo 'Incorrect Value';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How does it make sense to post exactly the same answer as I did? If you want to contribute provide some other way to do it.

Comment: If you look clearly it is not the same answer, <?php $myValue; ?>, yours misses a semi colon

Comment: Thanks, @chyke007! Do I need to add that semicolon after `$myValue`?

Comment: @chyke007 Semicolon will not make sense there unless you write any other statement after it.

Comment: @BigSantuary technically it will not matter unless you write something after that. But I recommend you to put it for uniformity and avoid confusions(like we are having now :) ).

Comment: Added it to show how it is done incase a second statement is needed.

Comment: This code will throw error as it’s missing semi colon at this line `$myValue='Hi there!'’

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying your code (which you should always do when debugging!) you have this:

```php
$myValue = 'Hi there!';
echo <<<JS001
<script type="text/javascript">
var msg = {$myValue};
</script>
JS001;
```

If you look at the HTML that's returned to the browser, you'll see that it looks like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var msg = Hi there!;
</script>
```

The browser has no idea that "Hi there!" was supposed to be a string, so it tries to execute it as code.

What you wanted the output to be was this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var msg = 'Hi there!';
</script>
```

So we need to add those quote marks into the PHP:

```php
$myValue = 'Hi there!';
echo <<<JS001
<script type="text/javascript">
var msg = '{$myValue}';
</script>
JS001;
```

As a more general solution, you can abuse the fact that JSON strings are valid JS values, and use `json_encode` in the PHP:

```php
$myValue = 'Hi there!';
$myValueJson = json_encode($myValue);
echo <<<JS001
<script type="text/javascript">
var msg = {$myValueJson};
</script>
JS001;
```

This makes no difference in this case, but is useful for passing other types of value - arrays, `null`, etc

Answer (score 0):

For a better code management, you should probably separate HTML, PHP, and JS code in different files.

Imagine something like this :

controller.php

```php
$displayName="David";

include 'vue.php';
```

vue.php

```php
<html>
...
<body>

<div id="php-data" data-displayName="<?php echo $displayName ?>"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
<script>
var msg = document.getElementById('php-data').dataset.displayName // "David";

</script>
```